# getting sum of count() in groupby

Tags: mysql, sql

Dont know if i am breaking comuntiy guidelines by posting a continuation question as new question. If so. I am sorry!!

Now, using,

```
SELECT count(alertid) as cnt,date(alertdate) as alertDate 
FROM alertmaster a,subscriptionmaster s 
WHERE alertDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() 
GROUP BY date(alertDate),s.subId 
ORDER BY a.alertDate DESC;
```

produces:
**13, '2011-04-08'

13, '2011-04-08'

13, '2011-04-08'

14, '2011-04-07'

13, '2011-04-07'**

Where I want is:

**39, '2011-04-08'

27, '2011-04-07'**

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting more than one row per date is because you have `GROUP BY date(alertDate),s.subId`. Just change your `GROUP BY` to

```
GROUP BY date(alertDate)
```

If you don't actually want separate groups for each `s.subId,date` combination.

Also the code you posted is missing a `JOIN` condition. This is one reason why using the explicit (ANSI 92) `JOIN` syntax is preferred.

Comment: thnx a lot. luking at my previous two questions.. And their answers.. seems i need to work on sql queries..

Comment: You also seem to be missing a `JOIN` condition I think. How are the 2 tables supposed to be related?

Comment: oh yes.. while editing i guess i removed the wrong portion.. thnx for drwng my attention